# How to share a method between classes defined via Ruby Struct?

Tags: ruby

Given a set of classes defined using Structs, like :

```
K1=Struct.new(:a,:b)
K2=Struct.new(:c,:d)
...
```

is it still possible to add a single common method :foo to every class defined that way, or do I need a deep refactoring ?

Factoring such behaviors is normally done using inheritance (or mixins), but I don't know if such a factoring is now still possible, starting with such struct-based class definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply mix a module into both structures.

```
module A
  def foo
  end
end

B = Struct.new :a, :b do include A end
C = Struct.new :c, :d do include A end

puts B.new.respond_to? :foo  # => true
puts C.new.respond_to? :foo  # => true
```

See [`Module#include`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-include) and [`Object#extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-extend) for detailed documentation on how this works.